# Basic Android Interaction with MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

This is my first attempt at making an Android app interact with a MySQL database stored on a remote server. All I am trying to do at this point is to insert a single record into an empty remote table. Basically, I'm just trying to establish a connection and write very simple data.

I'm not getting any errors, but my table is still empty after this runs. What am I doing wrong???

/my_db/test.php

```
    include('connection.php');

    $name='dummy';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('$name')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$result) {return -1;}

    return 1;
?>
```

This is in the onCreate function of my Activity:

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //Avoiding threading issues for the moment
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String testURL = context.getResources().getString(R.string.dbURL) + "my_db/test.php";
        System.err.println(testURL); //output looks good 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/my_db/test.php'
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(testURL);

        try
        {
            //not actually using the passed parameter for now
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", inputFullName.getText().toString()));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.err.println("done");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you know you don't get any errors?  Have you put a breakpoint on the cactch block?

Comment: It won't be in logcat since you eat the exception.

Comment: Hmm.. Everything that I read says that it should appear in the logcat. At any rate, see my new println statements above. I'm getting only the output "done" and no output "error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might check what the server response or the http response, because it seems that the code actually connect to the server side, but the server side failed to execute the query, you might try first to try the server side in web browser.

Comment: I think you are probably right. When I go into my browser, I type the following: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/my_db/test.php' and I get back 'No input file specified'. However, I can see in my FTP client that the file exists on the server in that exact location. Am I testing this correctly?

Comment: first check all the dependencies of your php file, it easy if you test it locally and test it on you browser first and when it succeed then test it on the android app.

Comment: I added some code on the Android side and I can see that same 'No input file specified.' error coming back to the device. My code works fine when I run it from an HTML doc on the same site, so somewhere there is a pointer issue or something where I'm not finding my file on the server. Thanks!

Comment: does the connection.php exist same on the test.php, is there any include statement on the connection.php, does it exist on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

First, Add mysql_close(); in your php, as you have to close the connection after the db operation is done, otherwise, it will occupy the system resource.

second, try to take care the response if it's 1 or -1, if -1, you may need to do some investigate in PHP side.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You're right. I need to close that connection.